# checkbox is not linked to model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EJoSadE/1#/users/index). Editing a user allows to change several things:

[image]

But clicking on the `active` checkbox has no effect. The  `name` is properly updated, though.

This is the relevant part of the template:

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name-id">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name" id="name-id" required="true"}}
            <i class="help-block">User's name</i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="active-id">Active</label>
      <div class="controls">
        {{view Ember.Checkbox valueBinding="active"}}
        <i class="help-block">Is this user active?</i>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What is the problem with the checkbox? Why is it not being updated in the backend (`FIXTURES` in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be checkedBinding

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="active"}}
```